# Wordpress update custom field with condition

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-fields

I want to update (change) a custom field (logo) value only if another custom field has the condition stated, then only if custom field "shop" is "Amazon".
I have this query

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_key`="logo",`meta_value`="http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/logo-amazon.png" WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'shop' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'Amazon'
```

but it doesn't work, it adds a new line in the table (I don't know how if I say update...). Could you please help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your query is wrong : you're trying to change the key and value of the meta that store the shop value.

What you want to do is this:

```
UPDATE
  `wp_postmeta` p1
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` p2
  ON p1.post_id = p2.post_id
SET
  p2.meta_value="http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/logo-amazon.png" 
WHERE
  p2.meta_key LIKE 'shop' AND p2.meta_value LIKE 'Amazon' AND
  p1.meta_key = "logo"
```

It will do an inner join on the update to get the posts ids that have the meta `shop` set to `Amazon` into `p2`, and update all the meta from `p1` that have the meta key `logo`.

Though considering you're using Wordpress, you could do this with a much easier way:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'shop',
      'value' => 'Amazon',
    )
  )
));
foreach($posts as $post) {
  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'logo', 'http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/logo-amazon.png');
}
```